# Docker swarm mode scale service issue with one worker

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

So, I am trying out Docker swarm mode in 1.12. Initially it took me time to figure out the mounts during docker service create, but I got that part to work. Now when I try to scale, it gives me the below error:

```
invalid bind mount source, so…
```

Is this error happening because I only have one worker and the mount is already set ?

Also, because I am binding ports, and if I have only one worker node will swarm still work if I scale the app to 3 or 5 apps ? How will Swarm handle port conflicts on just one worker node ?

Need some help with this.

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @vitorsdcs No. Are you facing a similar issue ?

Comment: Yeah, but I solved it. I figured out I had to create the folders I was mounting on the host machine before creating the services.